# Parsing json using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

My json file is of the format:

```
{
  "doc": {
    "BandDatabase": {
      "Artist1": {
        "-name": "john",
        "-instrument": "piano"
        "Artist2": [
          {
            "-name": "tina",
            "-instrument": "drums"
            "Manager": {
              "Person1": {
                "-name": "abby"
                }
```

I have my controller setup as :

```
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('js/artists.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.artists = data;
    });
```

How do I search for an element in the json format above? I am unable to display the name element on the webpage my doing the following:

```
<div ng-controller = "MyController">
    <ul class="artists">
        <li class="messages" ng-repeat="item in artists">
            <div class="info">
                <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
            </div>
```

I want to be able to display the name of Artist1 and Artist 2.

Comment: In your JSON file, is Artist2 a property of Artist1? Does Artist1 an object and Artist2 an array?

Answer (score 1):

[`JSON.Parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is part of `JavaScript` use it to convert `JSON` into `JavaScript Objects`.

```
$http.get('js/artists.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.artists = JSON.Parse(data).artists;
});
```

**BTW** your `JSON` looks rather strange to me... I imagine it should look more like this:

```
{
    "artists": [
        {
            "name": "kongor",
            "instrument": "gitar"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jacob",
            "instrument:" "...",
            "manager": {
                "name": "Cole"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Note that there is also an `angular.fromJson` function, but it's almost exactly the same thing:

`return isString(json) ? JSON.parse(json) : json;`